# Why does streaming a char pointer to cout not print an address?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char, cout

When I print a char pointer with `printf()`, it makes the decision with conversion specifier whether the address should be printed or the whole string according to %u or %s.

But when I want to do the same thing with `cout`, how  will `cout` decide what should be printed among address and whole string? Here is an example source:

```
int main()
{
  char ch='a';
  char *cptr=&ch;
  cout<<cptr<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Here, in my GNU compiler, `cout` is trying to output ch as a string.

How I can get address of `ch` via `cptr` using `cout`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cout << with char\* argument prints string, not pointer value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813423/cout-with-char-argument-prints-string-not-pointer-value)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Overload resolution selects the `ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const char *c);` which is used for printing C-style strings. You want the other `ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const void *p);` to be selected. You are probably best off with a cast here:

```
 cout << static_cast<void *>(cptr) << endl;
```

Comment: `static_cast<void*>` should be sufficient enough in this case, since we're talking about basic data type pointer.

Answer (score 7):

`cout` prints a string if it receives a `char *`, simple as that.

Here are the overloads for `operator <<` for `ostream`:

```
ostream& operator<< (bool val);
ostream& operator<< (short val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned short val);
ostream& operator<< (int val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned int val);
ostream& operator<< (long val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned long val);
ostream& operator<< (float val);
ostream& operator<< (double val);
ostream& operator<< (long double val);
ostream& operator<< (const void* val);

ostream& operator<< (streambuf* sb);

ostream& operator<< (ostream& ( *pf )(ostream&));
ostream& operator<< (ios& ( *pf )(ios&));
ostream& operator<< (ios_base& ( *pf )(ios_base&));

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, char c );
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, signed char c );
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, unsigned char c );


//this is called
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const char* s );
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const signed char* s );
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const unsigned char* s );
```

If you want the address, you want:

```
ostream& operator<< (const void* val);
```

so you need to cast to `const void*`.

Answer (score 4):

I would just cast it to a void* so it doesn't try to interpret it as a C-string:

```
cout << (void*) cptr << endl;
```

However, a safer option would be to use static_cast as in dirkgently's answer (that way the cast is at least checked at compile time).

Comment: c-style cast ? wouldn't it be safer to use a c++ cast ?

Comment: @AdrienPlisson It's less safe than C++ casts other than reinterpret_cast.  In a case as trivial as this, I wouldn't bother with a C++ style cast, though I suppose for completeness, I should mention it.  It's hard to foresee a situation in which a cast to void* just to cout it would end up being harmful, though I'm sure once a code base got large enough, some really weird casting could happen.

Comment: @Corbin: For `void *`, C++11's `reinterpret_cast` is just okay. See [Issue #1120](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1120).

Answer (score 0):

As Luchian said, cout knows what to print based on the type. If you want to print the pointer value, you should cast the pointer to void* which will be interpated as a pointer.