# Printing C++ int pointer vs char pointer

Tags: c++, string, pointers

When I run the following code:

```
int i[] = {1,2,3};
int* pointer = i;
cout << i << endl;

char c[] = {'a','b','c','\0'};
char* ptr = c;
cout << ptr << endl;
```

I get this output:

```
0x28ff1c
abc
```

Why does the int pointer return the address while the char pointer returns the actual content of the array?

Comment: Becuase of how cout works. cout recognizes ptr as a `char *` which cout treats as a null-terminated string, and thus prints out the contents instead of the pointer address. Cast ptr to `unsigned int` or `uintptr_t` too see the address...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cout << with char\* argument prints string, not pointer value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813423/cout-with-char-argument-prints-string-not-pointer-value)

Comment: Another very useful answer, with all the overloads for `operator <<` for `ostream`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10869485/3982001

Answer (score 6):

This is due to overload of `<<` operator. For `char *` it interprets it as null terminated C string. For `int` pointer, you just get the address.

Answer (score 1):

The [operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx)

> cout <<

is overload 'char *' so it knows how to handle it (in this case, printing all chars till the end one).

But for int is not, so it just prints out the 'memory address'

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to `char` is the same type as a string literal. So for the sake of simplicity, `cout` will print the content of the char array as if it was a string. So when you are doing this:

```
cout << "Some text" << endl;
```

It does not print the address, the same way as your code is doing.

If you want to pring the address, cast it to `size_t`

```
cout << reinterpret_cast<size_t>(ptr) << endl;
```