# Null pointer Exception ( int Vs char)

Tags: c++, pointers

Program 1:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
   int  *ptr = NULL;
   cout << "The value of ptr is " << ptr ;
   return 0;
}
```

Program 2:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
   char  *ptr = NULL;
   cout << "The value of ptr is " << ptr ;
   return 0;
}
```

The question is,In the Program 1 the output is stable as :

```
  The value of ptr is 00000000
```

while,in the Program 2,instead of int pointer I used char pointer and it gives me an Exception.

can anyone help me with the understanding?

Answer (score 3):

Because the << operator isn't dereferencing the int* in the first program, it's simply printing the value of the pointer as 0. But in the second program the << operator is attempting to dereference the pointer as a string, which crashes.

Comment: Can i avoid the de-referencing in the char pointer case?

Comment: @MukeshPareek see [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869459/char-pointer-confusing-with-cout-in-c).

Comment: You can cast the char* as an int, like: (int)ptr

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for the link