# For a char d, I get strange output when executing cout << &d

Tags: c++, char, cout, ampersand, addressof

i just started to learn c++, and I don't really understand, why when I cout &d, it shows up the char d as many times as i have showed it up already + add 1 time.
So it shows 3 time the char "d" here... for the line
*cout << &d << endl;*

if someone can explain me why, with simple word, i would thanks him.
And i'm sorry if the question is stupid.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{

char d('d');

cout << d << endl;
cout << d << endl;
cout << &d << endl;


    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869459/why-does-streaming-a-char-pointer-to-cout-not-print-an-address

Comment: When you use the address-of operator `&` you get a pointer to the variable you get the address of. If the variable is of type `char` then the pointer to it will be of type `char *`. Which is the common type for null-terminated byte ***strings***.

Comment: Should be reopened. This question is not about why I don't see the address, it is about from where the extra characters came, and why them changes when you change the single character.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `&` (in this context) is the address-of operator.

EDIT: As pointed out by @MSalters the C++ standard has this as Undefined Behavior, so anything can happen, but most current compilers will do the following:

So you're effectively passing a pointer to `char` to `cout.operator<<()`.  This is treated as a C-style string and will print everything at that memory address up to the next `\0` nul char. Your `'d'` is put there by your `char` initialization. The rest is pretty much randomly what's in memory after it.

Comment: Technically it's Undefined Behavior. You can't even rely on it printing the `'d'` itself; `std::cout` might very well crash on an access violation before it has constructed the string to print.

Comment: Good point @MSalters, added to answer.